# Installation error while using npm install react-native-gifted-messenger --save

Tags: node.js

### I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, node version 6, and npm version 5

---

Getting the following error while installing

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/p/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/p/package.json'
npm WARN p No description
npm WARN p No repository field.
npm WARN p No README data
npm WARN p No license field.
```

Any suggestions how to resolve it would be appreciated.

Comment: where are you running this command ?

Comment: In the home directory